# Using validationEngine for single field in the form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validation-engine

I am using validationEngine for my form validation. I use

```
$('#myForm').validationEngine('validate')
```

for form. But now I am validating my form in parts. So is there a way I can validate field one by one. Something like

```
$('#form').validationEngine('validateField', 'email')
```

Please suggest!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[**ValidationEngine**](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html) made every thing to be more simple.  It already has predefined which can be used like

```
class="validate[required,custom[email]]" //for email
class="validate[required,equals[password]] text-input" //for password
```

By adding the respective class name you can validate it, also check this in [GitHub](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

Comment: Just to clarify, So here I have 3 form fields in section. Divided complete form in 3 sections. Each section has "continue" button. So in section 1, I click continue and close the section. The section closes only if 3 fields are validated. This technique will work on continue button click??? Thanks